# calculadora en asp.net en visual studio no realiza operaciones

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy realizando una calculadora en visual studio asp.net, y al momento de realizar operaciones no se realizan,al parecer "memoria1" llega como 0 al momento de usarlo en "Calculadora()" al igual que la variable "signo" llegan sin nada, no encuentro el error
anexo codigo:

```
public partial class wfCalculadora : System.Web.UI.Page
//primero declaro las variables    
{

    double memoria1;
    double memoria2;
    double resultado;
    string signo;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a signo el "+",limpiando el texbox por ultimo        
        {          
                if (txtInsertar.Text!= "")
                {
                    memoria1 = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                    signo = "+";
                    txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                }              
        }

        protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 1
        {

            txtInsertar.Text += "1";
        }

        protected void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 0
        {

            txtInsertar.Text += "0";
        }

        protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 2
        {

            txtInsertar.Text += "2";
        }

        protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 3
        {
            txtInsertar.Text += "3";
        }

        protected void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 4
        {
            txtInsertar.Text += "4";
        }

        protected void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 5
        {
            txtInsertar.Text += "5";
        }

        protected void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 6
        {
            txtInsertar.Text += "6";
        }

        protected void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 7
        {
            txtInsertar.Text += "7";
        }

        protected void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 8
        {
            txtInsertar.Text += "8";
        }

        protected void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // se programa el boton 9
        {
            txtInsertar.Text += "9";
        }

        protected void btnrestar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a signo el "-",limpiando el texbox por ultimo 
        {
              try
              {
                if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
                {
                    memoria1 = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                    signo = "-";
                    txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void btnmultiplicar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a signo el "*",limpiando el texbox por ultimo 
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
                {
                    memoria1 = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                    signo = "*";
                    txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void btndividir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a signo el "/",limpiando el texbox por ultimo 
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
                {
                    memoria1 = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                    signo = "/";
                    txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void btnCE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se programa el boton de borrar todo
        {
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            memoria1 = 0.0;
            memoria2 = 0.0;
            signo = string.Empty;
        }

        protected void btnborrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se programa el boton de borrar solo 1 hacia la izquierda
        {
            try
            {
                int largo = 0;
                if(txtInsertar.Text != "")
                {
                    largo = txtInsertar.Text.Length;
                    txtInsertar.Text=txtInsertar.Text.Substring( 0,largo-1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void btnmasomenos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se programa el boton para cambiar de signo
        {
            int cambiars = 0;
            try
            {
                if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
                {
                    cambiars= int.Parse(txtInsertar.Text)*(-1);
                }
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInsertar.Text += cambiars;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void btncoma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se programa el boton para poner una ";"
        {
            if(txtInsertar.Text != "")
            {
                txtInsertar.Text = txtInsertar.Text + ",";
            }else
            {
                txtInsertar.Text = "0,";
            }
        }

        protected void btnigual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //aqui al presionar el boton igual, se toma lo del texbox y se guarda en "memoria2" y se corre el metodo "Calculadora()"
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtInsertar.Text != "" && memoria1!= 0.0 )
                {
                    memoria2 = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                    Calculadora();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void Calculadora()
        //Aqui dependiendo del signo se realiza la operacion necesaria y se muestra en el textbox
        {               
            if (signo.Equals("+"))
            {
                resultado = memoria1 + memoria2;
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
            }
            else
                if (signo.Equals("-"))
            {

                resultado = memoria1 - memoria2;
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
            }
            else
                if (signo.Equals("*"))
            {
                resultado = memoria1 * memoria2;
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
            }
            else
                if (signo.Equals("/"))
            {
                resultado = memoria1 / memoria2;
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
            }
        }

        protected void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //se programa el boton de borrar solo el texbox
        {
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se debe al modelo de ejecución que tiene ASP.Net WebForms, todos los botones que usted tiene hacen postback y cada vez que se va al servidor se pierden los valores de las variables memoria1, memoria2, resultado y signo, mi propuesta sería almacenar estos valores en una variable de [ViewState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.viewstate) o en una variable de [Session](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session) si se sigue manejando una estrategia del lado del servidor. La otra forma sería implementar una solución desde el lado del cliente con Javascript.

Adjunto el código con el ajuste utilizando ViewState.

```
public partial class wfCalculadora : System.Web.UI.Page
{   
    double resultado;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 1
    {

        txtInsertar.Text += "1";
    }

    protected void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 0
    {

        txtInsertar.Text += "0";
    }

    protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 2
    {

        txtInsertar.Text += "2";
    }

    protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 3
    {
        txtInsertar.Text += "3";
    }

    protected void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 4
    {
        txtInsertar.Text += "4";
    }

    protected void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 5
    {
        txtInsertar.Text += "5";
    }

    protected void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 6
    {
        txtInsertar.Text += "6";
    }

    protected void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 7
    {
        txtInsertar.Text += "7";
    }

    protected void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 8
    {
        txtInsertar.Text += "8";
    }

    protected void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // se programa el boton 9
    {
        txtInsertar.Text += "9";
    }

    protected void btnSumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a ViewState["signo"] el "+",limpiando el texbox por ultimo        
    {
        if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
        {
            ViewState["memoria1"]= double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
            ViewState["signo"] = "+";
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected void btnrestar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a ViewState["signo"] el "-",limpiando el texbox por ultimo 
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
            {
                ViewState["memoria1"] = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                ViewState["signo"] = "-";
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void btnmultiplicar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a ViewState["signo"] el "*",limpiando el texbox por ultimo 
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
            {
                ViewState["memoria1"] = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                ViewState["signo"] = "*";
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void btndividir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se agrega lo del texbox a memoria1 y a ViewState["signo"] el "/",limpiando el texbox por ultimo 
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
            {
                ViewState["memoria1"] = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                ViewState["signo"] = "/";
                txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void btnCE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se programa el boton de borrar todo
    {
        txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
        ViewState["memoria1"] = 0.0;
        ViewState["memoria2"] = 0.0;
        ViewState["signo"] = string.Empty;
    }

    protected void btnborrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se programa el boton de borrar solo 1 hacia la izquierda
    {
        try
        {
            int largo = 0;
            if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
            {
                largo = txtInsertar.Text.Length;
                txtInsertar.Text = txtInsertar.Text.Substring(0, largo - 1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void btnmasomenos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se programa el boton para cambiar de ViewState["signo"]
    {
        int cambiars = 0;
        try
        {
            if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
            {
                cambiars = int.Parse(txtInsertar.Text) * (-1);
            }
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            txtInsertar.Text += cambiars;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void btncoma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se programa el boton para poner una ";"
    {
        if (txtInsertar.Text != "")
        {
            txtInsertar.Text = txtInsertar.Text + ",";
        }
        else
        {
            txtInsertar.Text = "0,";
        }
    }

    protected void btnigual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //aqui al presionar el boton igual, se toma lo del texbox y se guarda en "memoria2" y se corre el metodo "Calculadora()"
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtInsertar.Text != "" && (double)ViewState["memoria1"] != 0.0)
            {
                ViewState["memoria2"] = double.Parse(txtInsertar.Text);
                Calculadora();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void Calculadora()
    //Aqui dependiendo del ViewState["signo"] se realiza la operacion necesaria y se muestra en el textbox
    {
        if (ViewState["signo"].Equals("+"))
        {   
            resultado = (double)ViewState["memoria1"] + (double)ViewState["memoria2"];
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
        }
        else
            if (ViewState["signo"].Equals("-"))
        {

            resultado = (double)ViewState["memoria1"] - (double)ViewState["memoria2"]; ;
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
        }
        else
            if (ViewState["signo"].Equals("*"))
        {
            resultado = (double)ViewState["memoria1"] * (double)ViewState["memoria2"]; ;
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
        }
        else
            if (ViewState["signo"].Equals("/"))
        {
            resultado = (double)ViewState["memoria1"] / (double)ViewState["memoria2"]; ;
            txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
            txtInsertar.Text += resultado;
        }
    }

    protected void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //se programa el boton de borrar solo el texbox
    {
        txtInsertar.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, Muchas gracias por la respuesta,apenas estoy aprendiendo sobre asp, con el viewstate me funciona perfectamente,Gracias.